# Detect sharp changes in elevation

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, dem, watershed, flood

I've been scouring the forums to see if there is a way to detect sharp, unnatural elevation changes greater than a certain amount in ArcGIS Pro. I've run across an issue in some DEMs where there are drop offs in a relatively flat area where there shouldn't be, likely due to mosaicking. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Slope tool then threshold the value?

Answer (score 1):

Use the slope tool in Arc with D8 or Dinf checked, and output set as degree. It will generate a raster which you can then threshold in your raster calculator. These sharp changes are likely above 85° so you can use a conditional such as *'if('slope.tif' > 85, 1, 0)'* such that (condition, 1 if true, 0 if false).

Assuming you want to investigate where these sharp lines are occurring, convert this new binary raster to polygon using the polygonize tool and apply a small buffer to highlight these areas encountering this issue.